# How To add grant to a new user for using jooq and mysql

Tags: mysql, jooq

I use JOOQ 3.6.2 and mysql 5.5.

I would like to use the JOOQ with appropriate permission.
My Application uses SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE.

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, LOCK TABLES ON `example`.* TO 'example_user'@'192.168.0.14'
```

Jooq throw DataAccessException:

```
SELECT command denied to user 'example_user'@'192.168.0.14'
```

JOOQ reauired "read mysql meta data", but I can't add grant to user.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON information_schema.* TO 'example_user'@'192.168.0.14';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR root@localhost;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Are there no other ways to allow all?

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'example_user'@'192.168.0.14';
```

Comment: Is running the code generator with user `root` instead of with user `example_user` an option in your environment? Also, what query is jOOQ trying to run when there is an access denied exception?

Comment: Thank you for your replay.
I had generated the source code from production database with root user, and application would use test_production database and test_production's user and url. But JOOQ accessed to production database with test_production's user. I generate source code from test_production database, and then I can get data. JOOQ seems not to use the url parameter of database name:jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/database_name.

Comment: I created production database and copied test_production database. How to use these database from same source code by switching configuration file in which each user and url are written?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking now. Is this still the same question? In any case, if you have multiple environments, you can take advantage of jOOQ's schema mapping functionality, either at code generation time, or at runtime: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/schema-mapping and http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/runtime-schema-mapping

Comment: Thanks to your help, I can notice I took it for granted that JOOQ access to url. I should have separate question. I'm grand for your kind reply.

Comment: Sure, just ask - I'll be there to respond :)